# umount /home does not work

Tags: mount, home, unmounting

I trying to merge my separate /home partition with my / partition in linux mint 13. 
I was told to umount /home, mount it on a different location and copy the contents to the /home directory on the / partition.

I have tried, but I cannot umount /home. When I try to do so, I get a message:

```
umount: /home device is busy (which processes use this device can be possibly be found with lsof or fuser)
```

How can I unmount my /home and mount it on a separate location (/dev/sda2/mnt/home) to be able to copy the contents to /home?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> umount: /home device is busy

This means that you (or someone) is currently using files on the `/home` filesystem.  The simplest solution is to have all normal users logout of the system and then log back in as root.

(You might need to configure the system to "Allow local system administrator login" in the Login Window application, Security tab.)

If umount still complains, then, as the error message states, have a look at the output of:

```
lsof /home
```

and,

```
fuser -mv /home
```

These commands will show you what processes have open files on the `/home` filesystem so you can go about closing them.

Note that something as seemingly innocent as having a terminal/console open with `/home` as the current working directory will cause `/home` to be in use and will stop `umount /home`.

Comment: how can I enable the system to 'allow local system administrator login' in mint?

Comment: @DutchArjo According to [this source](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=134519), it should be under the Login Window application, Security tab.

Comment: Hello @DutchArjo. On unix's lyke OS, you can go to single mode user using `Ctrl Alt <F1-F6>`. Once there, you can use `root` as login. Of course, you need to log out of another user accounts before. I hope this can help you!

Comment: @sgmart, no, you go to single user mode either by using the 's' option when booting up, or `init s` or `shutdown`.  Ctrl-alt-F1 just switches to the first text mode virtual terminal.  I believe mint, like ubuntu, has the root account locked by default so this is the only way to log in as root ( you can't login as root on a virtual tty when not in single user mode ).

Comment: Ok, I'm glad to read this. I just can say login as root is the key here; then thanks @psusi, on resume: enable root login, got to virtual tty `Ctrl Alt F4`, login as root and proceed...

Comment: I see a kernel mount line even if no user processes access `/home`. What is going on with that?

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney To answer that, we might need a lot more info.  It might be best if you open up a new question and provide the relevant output from lsof and fuser.

Answer (score 9):

I was having this problem in Google Compute engine, where I have setup /home as a separate partition.

In this case you can never log in as root, you must login as a user, then switch to root, so it was never possible to `umount /home`

My solution was to login as my normal user

```
ssh myuser@myvm
```

Then once inside I switched to root and closed my own session like this:

```
cd /
exec sudo su
```

First I went to the root folder in case my home folder complained about being in use. Then I replace my current bash session with a root session by prepending `exec` to `sudo su`

Now I could `umount /home` without issues.

Comment: This is a good answer too, it helped me resize my own /home partition on a VPS

Comment: In Linux not being able to "log in" as root has nothing to do with the `/home` folder whether it is a separate partition or not; your post of *ssh myuser@myvm* for logging in is over ssh and it's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` having `PermitRootLogin no` is the reason why you cannot login [via ssh] as root.  `/etc/passwd` should show the root home folder as `/root/` which is not under the `/home` folder, unless someone manually changed the home folder for the root account to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

Since the error message suggest that run `lsof` or `fuser` to show which process is using `/home`, you should try:

```
$ fuser -v /home/
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/home:               root     kernel mount /home
```

With `lsof` the output can be longer.

The simple solution for you is trying to modify `/etc/fstab` to mount `/home` to different partition. Something like this:

```
/dev/sdb3    /home    ext4    defaults,noatime    0 2
```

Make sure to comment or remove old entry, restart and see the change.

Answer (score 2):

You undoubtedly have some processes that are using files in your home directory. All your processes probably have it as their working directory, for example. Your session manager may be logging to `~/.xsession-errors`, and so on.

#### If you've already done the move

When you moved your home directory to a different filesystem, you copied the files and removed the old ones. But you can't make running processes switch to the new files (not unless they have a feature to do that).

You'll need to log out and back in. When you log in now, the processes will be using your new home directory.

You can see which processes are still using your old home directory (or anything else on the home filesystem) by running `fuser /home` or `lsof /home`. Once you kill these processes, you'll be able to unmount `/home`. You can use `fuser -k /home` to kill them all (carefully check what they are before doing this!).

#### Better way to do the move

Ideally, you should move your home directory while not logged in, because your running processes might want to save data (e.g. saving your current session) and some will use the file that they already have open. You can do the move by logging in on a text console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and logging in as root (make sure you have a root password configured). Move the content of `/home` to a new directory, then unmount the empty filesystem and move the directories around:

```
mkdir /home.new
mv /home/* /home.new/
umount /home
rmdir /home.new
mv /home.new /home
```

Or you can move the `/home` mount:

```
mkdir /home.old
mount --move /home /home.old
mv /home.old/* /home/
umount /home.old
rmdir /home.old
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thought is to reboot using the rescue disk, get a root shell, mount all the partitions and then do the cp -r of the old data to the new location, then do a sync and unmount all the partitions and reboot.  BTW, you can also modify the /etc/fstab table to make things the way you want on the mounted root partiton (not the rescue /etc/fstab).

Reboot then after that and all is good.

Answer (score 1):

> I trying to merge my separate /home partition with my / partition in
>   linux mint 13. I was told to umount /home, mount it on a different
>   location and copy the contents to the /home directory on the /
>   partition.

You can move your home directory to a new folder.

```
usermod -m -d /new_home/your_username your_username
```

You must do this to all of your users, after that, you can umount /home without problem.

Answer (score 1):

it is solved. I was not logged properly I guess. Once the root login was enabled in the startup screen security settings I was able to umount /sda5. mounted /sda5 to /mnt/home and from there do

```
cp -va /mnt/home/* /home
```

Resized and everything else and have my /home now on the / partition.

Resizing had to be done by booting from gparted cdrom.

it's working fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Something else that worked for me: I saw that sshd was keeping /home open and wouldn't let me unmount it. I found that a bash script was the culprit and killed it. that kicked my ssh session. But I was able to re-login right away and now was able to umount /home.